# Docker: mounting volume and run node apps

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

For the first time I am trying to use docker for development purpose. I have  a node apps .I want to run the apps from docker. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.0.0-slim
MAINTAINER pyprism

# Prepare app directory
RUN mkdir -p /src/

# Install dependencies
WORKDIR /src/

VOLUME .:/src/

RUN npm install

# Build the app
# RUN npm build

# Expose the app port
EXPOSE 8000

# Start the app
CMD npm start
```

and docker-compose file:

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - '8000:8000'
```

But when I run `docker-compose up`  I got this errors:

```
Building web
Step 1 : FROM node:6.0.0-slim
 ---> 7bf50b1ad9da
Step 2 : MAINTAINER pyprism
 ---> Running in d1defd389fe6
 ---> b684686c614d
Removing intermediate container d1defd389fe6
Step 3 : RUN mkdir -p /src/
 ---> Running in 36b64560f88f
 ---> 8eb6847d67e4
Removing intermediate container 36b64560f88f
Step 4 : WORKDIR /src/
 ---> Running in 00d4c1fd2cf5
 ---> 88a54e6af176
Removing intermediate container 00d4c1fd2cf5
Step 5 : VOLUME .:/src/
 ---> Running in dc0e9d9d973a
 ---> b558f03ce63c
Removing intermediate container dc0e9d9d973a
Step 6 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 09445786b71e
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.8.6
npm info using node@v6.0.0
npm info lifecycle undefined~preinstall: undefined
npm info linkStuff !invalid#1
npm info lifecycle undefined~install: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~postinstall: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~prepublish: undefined
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/package.json'
npm WARN src No description
npm WARN src No repository field.
npm WARN src No README data
npm WARN src No license field.
npm info ok 
 ---> 8c544294e6c5
Removing intermediate container 09445786b71e
Step 7 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Running in 965e192bc67e
 ---> daaf52fac6ca
Removing intermediate container 965e192bc67e
Step 8 : CMD npm start
 ---> Running in 890549e3aea7
 ---> 19a3dc786cee
Removing intermediate container 890549e3aea7
Successfully built 19a3dc786cee
WARNING: Image for service web was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating redux_web_1
Attaching to redux_web_1
web_1  | npm info it worked if it ends with ok
web_1  | npm info using npm@3.8.6
web_1  | npm info using node@v6.0.0
web_1  | npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-22-generic
web_1  | npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
web_1  | npm ERR! node v6.0.0
web_1  | npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
web_1  | npm ERR! path /src/package.json
web_1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
web_1  | npm ERR! errno -2
web_1  | npm ERR! syscall open
web_1  | 
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/package.json'
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/package.json'
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
web_1  | npm ERR! enoent 
web_1  | 
web_1  | npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
web_1  | npm ERR!     /src/npm-debug.log
redux_web_1 exited with code 254
```

Comment: Why do you use a volume? You should use `COPY` or `ADD` commands to get your changes reflected. Use volumes for data that you want to keep while you are updating your app.

Comment: I try to use `ADD . /src/` .  It doesn't  reflect my changes.

Comment: check out this repo: https://github.com/b00giZm/docker-compose-nodejs-examples/tree/master/00-basic-express-generator and have a look at `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not the right way to use the instruction VOLUME in dockerfile. 
As documentation says “The VOLUME instruction creates a mount point with the specified name and marks it as holding externally mounted volumes from native host or other containers”, and I don't think is what you want to do.

You don’t need to specify the VOLUME instruction and you don’t need to create the src directoy. Modify the Dockerfile as below:

```
FROM node:6.0.0-slim
MAINTAINER pyprism

# Install dependencies
WORKDIR /src/

RUN npm install

# Expose the app port
EXPOSE 8000

# Start the app
CMD npm start
```

Now you can navigate to the Dockerfile directory and build the image:

```
$docker build -t node .
```

Then run the container using the –v option to mount your local directory, as below:

```
 $docker run -p 8000:8000 -v path/to/code/dir:/src/ <image-name>
```

this will mount your code directory in /src.

if you want to use docker compose simply specify the volumes in the docker-compose.yml file:

```
 web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - path/to/code/dir:/src/ 
  ports:
   - '8000:8000'
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't do this `VOLUME .:/src/` in a dockerfile. It's not legal syntax to specify a host mount point in a dockerfile as it would render it host dependent. Move the volume mapping definition to your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 8):

I am adding this answer just in case the accepted solution does not work for others as it did not for me.  Though I confess I am NOT a docker nor a node expert.

This is what I had:
Dockerfile

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/src/

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4200

CMD npm start
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  frontend:
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/usr/src
```

To make it work for me I had to remove `RUN npm install` from the Dockerfile and change the cmd to `CMD npm install && npm start`

I think the issue is that the volume is not mounted when RUN executes, but is only mounted right before CMD.  Also note that you will have to re-build your image after editing Dockerfile.

This did work for me but again, I am no expert.  So if anyone has any thoughts or ideas please feel free to explain in the comments or edit to improve the answer.

Comment: RUN is an image build step, the state of the container after a RUN command will be committed to the container image. 

CMD is the command the container executes by default when you launch the built image. A Dockerfile will only use the final CMD defined.

In my case "npm install" was missing "package*.json" which I fixed by adding after "WORKDIR": `COPY package*.json ./`. Then "RUN" executed without errors